# What's the module name of built-in predicate 'term_string/3' in SWI-Prolog 7.1.3?

Tags: module, prolog, predicate, swi-prolog, built-in

I am using a framework that has globally overridden the built-in predicate `term_string/3` with different behaviour.
Now i would like to use the built-in one, but what is its module name?
I would like to call `<ItsModuleName>:term_string(..)`

I know that list operations have a separate module `:- use_module(library(lists))` that can be referred to explicitly by
`lists:append(..)` for example.
I have searched through the documentation on the web and in the SWI manual but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the properties of a predicate using the standard `predicate_property/2` predicate. In this case we get:

```
?- predicate_property(term_string(_,_,_), P).
P = interpreted ;
P = visible ;
P = built_in ;
P = static ;
P = imported_from('$syspreds') ;
P = file('/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl-7.3.1/boot/syspred.pl') ;
P = line_count(1196) ;
P = nodebug ;
P = number_of_clauses(2) ;
P = number_of_rules(2) ;
false.
```

The property you want is `imported_from(Module)`, which ins this case tells you that the predicate `temr_String/3` is exported from module `'$syspreds'`. But given that this modules defines system built-in predicates, you should be able to use as alternative `system:term_string(...)` as the documentation states that "Module `user` imports from `system` where all built-in predicates reside.".